# Fermat's Little Theorem definition in SICP

Tags: number-theory

I am reading [Structure And Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs) and I have a question regarding their definition of Fermat's Little Theorem. On page 51 the authors of the book define Fermat's Little Theorem as follows:

> If $n$ is a prime number and $a$ is any positive integer less than $n$, then $a$ raised to the $n$th power is congruent to $a$ modulo $n$.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) on Fermat's Little Theorem defines the theorem as follows:

> If $p$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$, the number $a^p − a$ is an integer multiple of $p$.

Now I am confused; should $a$ by less than $n$ as the book states, or can $a$ be any positive integer? In other words, is the definition in the book too restrictive on $a$?

Comment: It's true for all integers $a$. The definition in the book is more restrictive than it needs to be.

Comment: Wikipedia is correct - the SICP restriction is not required.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification!

Comment: But you know, you could have proved for yourself that the book’s formulation implies the Wikipedia formulation.